# Free resources related to a process without killing it

Tags: c#, .net

I export huge amount of data from the database (images in particular) I tried to dispose the objects but it seems like memory allocation keeps on piling up. please help here's my code

```
foreach (var v in EntityFrameworkContext.GetInstance.DbContext.ATasks.ToList())                         
{

    if (v.TaskImages.Count == 0)
        continue;

    var dir = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", txtDumpFolder.Text, v.Id);

    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", txtDumpFolder.Text, v.Id));

    lstLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            lstLog.Items.Add("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            lstLog.Items.Add(string.Format("DIRECTORY: {0} Created.", dir));

            int visibleItems = lstLog.ClientSize.Height / lstLog.ItemHeight;
            lstLog.TopIndex = Math.Max(lstLog.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0);
        });

    v.TaskImages.ToList().ForEach(a =>
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(a.Image)))
        {
            PropertyItem[] pi = bmp.PropertyItems;
            bmp.Save(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.jpg", dir, a.Id), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            LogMessage(string.Format("IMAGE: {0} \n exported.", a.Id));
        }
    });
    GC.Collect();
};
```

}

Comment: `GC.Collect()` is almost never the answer. How do you manage/close the DatabaseContext ?

Comment: The title of this question gives me goosebumps. Freeing a process's resources without killing it is like tearing down a house before you move out of it. Not recommended. If you are leaking memory, then you need to address that. Use a memory profiler for help.

Comment: Task Manager is not for you.  Do NOT look at it.  Do NOT worry about memory management, it is not for you.  Only worry about this stuff when you are getting OOM exceptions.  You aren't disposing of your MemoryStream, which may be a problem.  Can't tell what the `a.Image` type is, assuming it's a byte array which is fine.

Comment: Well thanks for response, I'm using Singleton pattern, I just realised that I don't close it, I will try that now. Thanks you very much